# unlink image using function in php

Tags: php, image, unlink

Please help me how can i unlink a image when i delete a product.I dont know where is my error in my code .Thank everyone so much.I tried different way to resolve this problem.I teached myself learn to code on youtube, and then I tried to create another model.Please help me solve this problem.

**Html Page**

```
<h3>List Product</h3>
    <table id="user">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Serial</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Price</th>

                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <?php
        if(!empty($_GET['msg'])){
            $msg = unserialize(urldecode($_GET['msg']));
            foreach ($msg as $key => $value){
                echo '<span style="color:blue;font-weight:bold">'.$value.'</span>';
            }
        }


        ?>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            $i = 0;
            foreach($listproduct as $key => $listpro){
                $i++;

            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $listpro['productName']; ?></td>
                <td><img src="<?php echo BASE_URL ?>/teamplate/image/<?php echo $listpro['image'];  ?>" width="60" height="60"></td>
                <td><?php echo $listpro['price']; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo $listpro['catName'] ?></td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    if($listpro['type']==0){
                        echo 'Feathered';
                    }else{
                        echo 'Non-Feathered';
                    }
                    ?>


                </td>
                <td><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL ?>/Product/delPro/<?php echo $listpro['productId'] ?>">Delete</a>
                || <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL ?>/Product/editPro/<?php echo $listpro['productId'] ?>">Edit</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>

        </tbody>



    </table>
```

**Function in Product page**

```
public function delPro($id = NULL){
            $tablePro = 'tbl_product';

            $this->data = array();
            $ProductModel = $this->load->model('ProductModel');
            $result = $ProductModel->delProductById($tablePro, $id);


            if($result == 1){
                        $this->data['productbyid'] = $ProductModel->updateProductById($tablePro, $id);
                        $path_unlink= BASE_URL."/teamplate/image/";
                        foreach($this->data['productbyid'] as $this->key => $this->value){
                                    $image_pro = $this->value['image'];
                                    unlink($path_unlink.$image_pro);
                            }


                        $mdata['msg'] = "Product Deleted Successfully...";


                    }else{
                        $mdata['msg'] = "Product Not Deleted...";
                    }
            $url = BASE_URL."/Product/ListProduct?msg=".urlencode(serialize($mdata));
                    header("Location:$url");

    }
```

**ProductModel Page**

```
public function updateProductById($tablePro, $id){
                $query = "SELECT * from $tablePro where productId = '$id'";
                return $this->db->select($query);
            }
```

Comment: What is the responsibility of delProductById() this method?

Comment: You need to give absolute path to unlink images. Url path will not work

Comment: The product already deleted ,but image not yet. url path I edited.